# Standardized radius of validity of normal coordinates in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, neighbourhood

Depending on the curvature of a certain manifold $M$, intuitively  it is interesting to quantify how quickly [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) defined at a point $p$ deteriorate away from $p$. Is there a standardized measure to quantify the actual size of the [neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) of $p$ the normal coordinates are valid in? If so, how is it calculated?

Comment: The standard term is the injectivity radius at $p$. This essentially tells you the largest ball under which normal coordinates are still well defined.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Thank you for the clarification! For the benefit of other visitors, following this terminology I found the following file explaining it: https://homepage.univie.ac.at/james.grant/papers/NullInj/Inj_rad_talk_1.pdf

Comment: There is also the conjugate radius, which can be estimated below using a lower bound of the sectional curvature.